# cassandra: how to connect cassandra cluster using lb?

Tags: cassandra

I am presently trying to setup cassandra cluster (4 nodes with 2 seeds) in our production env.
When i connect with comma seperated host name and port, it is working fine.

```
cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("Test Cluster", "host1:9160,host2:9160,host3:9160,host4:9160");
```

But when I configured a cluster name at the lb connecting to the individaul nodes and configured the same in Hector thrift client. But i got the below eception,

```
cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("Test Cluster", "lbname");
```

SEVERE: me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.

```
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException: All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client.
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.getClientFromLBPolicy(HConnectionManager.java:393)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:249)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.describeKeyspace(AbstractCluster.java:199)
        at com.july.storage.cassandra.util.CassandraDBUtil.getDb(CassandraDBUtil.java:107)
        at com.july.storage.cassandra.util.CassandraDBUtil.hasTable(CassandraDBUtil.java:91)
        at com.july.storage.cassandra.action.CassandraHandler.getCall(CassandraHandler.java:65)
        at com.july.storage.service.StorageService.GET(StorageService.java:58)
        at com.july.storage.cassandra.action.CassandraHandler.main(CassandraHandler.java:571)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a load balancer in front of Cassandra. Let your client connect to all of the nodes. A load balancer will just be a single point of failure, and add unnecessary latency.

Comment: If i want to add more nodes later, i need to go and change each and every clients which is using the cluster. Is there any other possibilities?

Comment: Most drivers have automatic peer discovery so they only need a seed node to connect and will then connection to all other nodes (or some, depending on configuration). For Hector scroll down to "Using Node Auto Discovery" in the user guide: https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/User-Guide

Comment: I am using cassandra 1.2.5. The cluster has 4 nodes. There are two seed nodes in the cluster. I have enabled AutoDiscoverHosts and used seed node for cluster creation in my client. If that seed node is up, i can able to write/ read data in all nodes in the cluster. but if it is down, "All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client" is throwing. No furthur read/write happens. 

(i) So is it mandatory to give all the nodes while creating cluster from the client eventhough we enable AutoDiscoverHosts?

Comment: If the node you're connecting to is down then there's no node to ask what other nodes are in the cluster.